# Advantages of using @Module NestJS

Tags: nestjs

I'm making a new NestJS app and after a lot of errors on the first because the multiple modules I created didn't have the correct `imports`, `providers`, `exports`, `TypeOrmModule.forFeature` etc made me wonder: What was the point?

Why not use only the `app.module` and just dump everything in it? All the controllers and services and entity types and any other that may come up?

From the documentation:

> We want to emphasize that modules are strongly recommended as an
> effective way to organize your components

Is that the only reason? Organization?
Does dependency injection play a role of some kind?

Edit:

If organization is the main reason, why not separate in a different folder with a controller and service? Basically a module without the imports, providers etc. Doing the same thing with less boilerplate.

Comment: had the same question ever since someone forced me to use angular. I find the module concept onerous. just desperate to use decorators and classes in a language that doesn't need or want them

Comment: NestJS copies Angular modules model, where it provides two main advantages: pure code organization and chunking app for lazy loading. Well, since then Angular introduced standalone components specifically to simplify mental model of code organization (does this mean that standard TS modules are good enough? I think yes). And lazy loading was never a desired feature for backend. So, I'd say modules in NestJS are useless, with few minor exceptions like libraries and maybe AppModule. That's just my opinion, though, and I'm not exactly a NestJS expert.

Answer (score 3):

> Why not use only the app.module and just dump everything in it?

Better yet, why use multiple files at all? Why not just have a couple thousand line `index.js` with no types, no organization, just raw JS all the way down?

The answer? Code organization and ease of re-use. By making these modules, you *should* be grouping together similar logic together. All  the code for a single feature *should* be available by just importing `FeatureModule` and usable. When it comes to library modules, this becomes pretty apparent: `TypeOrmModule` has a `forRoot/forRootAsync` and a `forFeature` which exposes ways to inject repositories into your services. The `JwtModule` has a `register/registerAsync` and exposes a `JwtService` so you can configure the `JwtService` once and re-use the provider.

When dealing with entity features this may look messier, but technically it's all still possible, so that in theory you'd be able to take `FeatureModule` from Application A and drop it into Application B and have everything still working with regards to the `FeatureModule`, similar to how [pulumi](https://www.pulumi.com/) has the idea of stacks and applications and you can just spin up new applications using the same group of components.

The module system, once you get the hang of it, and in my opinion, makes it very easy to recognize what all a module will be working with, with regards to other features and how they're connected. It's just a matter of discipline and learning the feature of the framework.

Comment: So the answer is yes? Organization only (and maybe, just maybe, reuse in another project)?